# ASP.NET MVC POST Route does not point to the correct Method

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I´ve got a problem with my current mvc project. 
I´m using an ajax call to send new comments to the server but the method does not even get called. 

My js code:

```
$("#answer_button").click(function () {
                showLoadingTab();
                var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("AnswerThread", "Threads")';
                var threadId = $("#threadId").val();
                var msg = $("#answer_msg").val();

                alert(actionUrl);
                alert(msg);
                alert(threadId);
                $.ajax({
                    url: actionUrl,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "Message=" + msg + "&threadId=" + threadId,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        hideLoadingTab();
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.");
                        hideLoadingTab();
                    }
                });
            });
```

as you see I´ve alerted the url, msg and threadId and they are all correct. url: "/Threads/AnswerThread", msg: "test", threadId: 1. 
I´ve already tried to put a breakpoint inside the AnswerThread method but it does not get called. The "AnswerThread" method is inside the "ThreadsController" and looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AnswerThread(string Message, int threadId)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        using (var db = new UnitOfWork(new BlogContext()))
        {
            db.Posts.Add(new Post()
            {
                Message = Message,
                PublishTime = DateTime.Now,
                ThreadId = threadId,
                UserId = userId
            });

            db.Complete();
        }

        return PartialView("/Views/Partial/Clear.cshtml");
    }
```

That´s exactly the same way I did it in the backend controllers but there it just works fine.
I hope somebody can help me..

UPDATE:
Made some changes just to try if any other way works. 
Change1 js:

```
var data = {
                    threadId: threadId,
                    Message: msg
                };


                $.ajax({
                    url: actionUrl,
                    type: "POST",
                    content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: data,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (msg.success == true) {
                            hideLoadingTab();
                            location.reload();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten: " + msg.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.");
                        hideLoadingTab();
                    }
                });
```

Change 2 c#:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AnswerThread([System.Web.Http.FromBody]PostDataModel data)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        string error = "";
        bool success = false;

        try
        {
            using (var db = new UnitOfWork(new BlogContext()))
            {
                db.Posts.Add(new Post()
                {
                    Message = data.Message,
                    PublishTime = DateTime.Now,
                    ThreadId = data.threadId,
                    UserId = userId
                });

                success = true;
                db.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
        }

        return Json(String.Format("'Success':'{0}', 'Error':'{1}'", success, error));
```

I tried this now with and without the "[FromBody]" statement. 
Oh yes and I´ve added the DataModel like this:

```
public class PostDataModel
{
    public int threadId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and I also tried to manually configure the pointed route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AnswerThread",
            url: "threads/answer",
            defaults: new { controller = "Threads", action = "AnswerThread" }
        );
```

The "actionUrl" variable in js get´s changed to /threads/answer but I´m always getting 500 Internal Server Error. When I put a breakpoint inside the method it does not stop at any point of the ajax call.

Comment: Are those parameters expected to be posted in the URL or in the body of the request?

Comment: I want to receive them from the "data" attribute of the ajax call. Don´t know if that´s something that get´s attached to the header or the body. I thought about trying to add "[FromBody]" but as I took a look to the other (working) methods from the backend controllers there are no [FromBody] statements

Comment: Does `#answer_button` exists at the time of the script execution? Is this a separate `.js` file or it's written into the view.

Comment: Your `msg` variable, being a string, could cause problems as a url variable.  I'd recommend wrapping this in JSON and posting the data rather than using a url variable, unless you _know_ you won't have character escape issues.

Comment: Your code should work. But it is not best to send the data via queruystring. What if user types a long message. Use the request body (data) to send the data. Check your browser dev tools->console / network tab to see whether there is any js erros / the call is made or it is getting a 200 OK response

Comment: @dcg yes it does. When i put an alert inside the .click event it also works. It´s written inside the view but into "scripts" section so jquery get´s loaded first.
yea I know that this is not the best way but it´s just for testing and I´m just typing something like "test" inside the textbox so I think this should work. The browser console shows me "500 Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome Dev Tools at the "Network" tab it says to me that there is a parameter called "id" which is null which causes to this 500 internal server error. I tried to find out more information about this but the error does not tell me where this parameter is located. 
I´ve got no parameter called "id" inside this method or the data model so where does this come from? 
**Solution**:
My Routes mapping was bad. I first mapped the route /threads/{id} and THEN did /threads/answer so when the /threads/answer got called it thought "answer" is an id so it tried to enter the "Index" method. So for my particular problem (and maybe for some other guys having the same issue) the solution was just to put the mapping of the /threads/answer route in front of the /threads/{id} route and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

Please check your parameter types, in controller **threadId is int** type and from ajax call you are passing **string** type.

**In Js**

```
 $("#answer_button").click(function () {
    showLoadingTab();
    var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("AnswerThread", "Home")';
    var threadId = parseInt($("#threadId").val());
    var msg = "Answer message";

    alert(threadId);
    $.ajax({
        url: actionUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: { Message: msg, threadId: threadId },
        success: function (msg) {
            hideLoadingTab();
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.");
            hideLoadingTab();
        }
    });
});
```

**In Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AnswerThread(string Message, int threadId)
    {
        return Json("Data");
    }
```

Comment: I tried it the other way round and set the "ThreadId" inside C# to string and converted it to int but doesn´t work.

Comment: if you needs to send string from ajax call than it must be strtng parameter in controller. please change as a string instead of "int threadId"

Comment: The "threadId" is an integer so I don´t have to change this. I changed to "parseInt" as you said (look at the update in the question) but this does not change anything.